Acer Aspire 5 "No Bootable Drive" after leaving it unplugged for several days
I run Debian 12 on my Acer Aspire 5 laptop and have not had any problems with it up until today. I believe I had left it in sleep mode while forgetting to plug it in to power for several days (first time ever) and now I receive a "No Bootable Drive" error on startup. I've looked at some tutorials that mentioned putting the UEFI setting into Legacy mode but I'm unable to make that change. I've also come across another post on here that suggested running a Boot-Repair report, which I've now done (the report can be read here - the final line under Suggested Repair says "The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.")
I'm completely lost so any help would be appreciated!
